# Proof explanation: There is no continuous complex square root function (specifically: why is $\varepsilon \circ \phi$ surjective on $[0, \pi]$?)

Tags: complex-numbers, proof-explanation

I'm struggling with an Analysis 1 proof which shows that there is no continuous square root function for complex numbers. Specifically I can't really wrap my head around the fact, that the given function composition is surjective on $[0, \pi]$. Let me give you more details. The problem was to proof the following:

> Assume there is a continuous function $w: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ with $w(z)^2 = z$. Hence, we have that $w(z^2) = \pm z$. This implies that there is a continuous function $\varepsilon : \mathbb{C}^* \rightarrow \{ -1, 1 \}$ with $\varepsilon (z) = \frac{w(z^2)}{z}$ and $\varepsilon (-z) = -\varepsilon (z)$. Show that such a function $\varepsilon$ doesn't exist.

I was provided with the following proof:

---

Let $\phi : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{*}, t \mapsto \exp(it)$. We know that $\phi$ is continuous, hence the composition $\varepsilon \circ \phi : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \{ -1, 1 \}$ is also continuous.

Because we have that

$$ (\varepsilon \circ \phi )(\pi) = \varepsilon (\exp(i\pi)) = \varepsilon(-1) = -\varepsilon(1) = -(\varepsilon \circ \phi )(0)$$

the function $\varepsilon \circ \phi$ is surjective on $[0, \pi]$.

*Why exactly is that the case? I know in a surjection we have that every element in the codomain corresponds to at least one element in the domain. But what about this equation tells me that $\varepsilon \circ \phi$ is surjective on $[0, \pi]$?*

Rest of the proof: $\varepsilon \circ \phi$ is continuous, so with the intermediate value theorem we know that
$$\exists z \in [0, \pi]\text{ with } (\varepsilon \circ \phi )(z) = 0$$
which leads to a contradiction because $0 \notin \{ -1, 1 \}$.

To many the answer may be very obvious, therefore I apologize for my rather stupid question. I'm still a beginner.

Comment: If $\epsilon(\phi(0)) = 1$, then $\epsilon(\phi(\pi)) = -1$. Since $1$ and $-1$ are the only points in the codomain, $\epsilon$ must be surjective. A similar argument applies if $\epsilon(\phi(0)) = -1$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog I see, thank you. But that wouldn’t that also mean that $\varepsilon \circ \phi$ is surjective on $\mathbb{R}$ and not just on $[0, \pi]$?

Comment: @PhyAC: Yes.  I think they're focusing on the closed interval $[0,\pi]$ to match the intermediate value theorem, which is usually stated for closed intervals.

Comment: And really, they're only using the term surjective to mean "it takes on both 1 and -1 at least once", without having to commit to where it does so.

Comment: Ah ok now I get it. I was so confused. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your question has been answered in the comments: The map $\psi = \epsilon \circ \phi \mid_{[0,\pi]} : [0,\pi ] \to \{-1,1\}$ is surjective because $\psi(\pi) = - \psi(0)$. Thus also $\epsilon \circ \phi : \mathbb R \to \{-1,1\}$ is surjective, but this is irrelevant. To apply the IVT, we just need to know that $\psi(\pi) = - \psi(0)$ and that $\psi$ is defined on $[0,\pi]$.

Let me remark that the specific map $\phi$ does not play an essential role. To apply the IVT, we can take **any** continuous map $f : [a, b] \to \mathbb C^*$ such that $f(a) = 1$ and $f(b) = -1$. There is a plethora of such maps, for example $f: [0,\pi] \to \mathbb C^*, f(t) = e^{it}$, or $f : [-1,1] \to \mathbb C^*, f(t) = t + i (1 - \lvert t \rvert)$.